# Find control in Nested listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm trying to find controls in a nested listview in a parent listview on postback.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    ListView ChildLV = (ListView)(LVParent.FindControl("ChildLV"));

    foreach (ListViewItem item in ChildLV.Items)
    {
        item.FindControl("NestListViewChildControl");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop the items in the parent ListView and use FindControl in each of those to locate the nested ListView.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in LVParent.Items)
    {
        ListView ChildLV = item.FindControl("ChildLV") as ListView;
    }
}
```

aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="LVParent" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:ListView ID="ChildLV" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: how can I Can't find inner control?
                foreach (ListViewItem item in LVParent.Items)
                {
                    ListView ChildLV= item.FindControl("ChildLV") as ListView;

                    foreach (ListViewItem DVitem in ChildLV.Items)
                    {
                        Label ChildLVLabel = DVitem.FindControl("ChildLVLabel ") as Label;
                        if (!object.Equals(ChildLVLabel , null))
                        {
                            var daa = ChildLV.Text;
                        }
                    }
                }